# how to remove last item from vector using std::move and update vector size

Tags: c++, memory, vector, move

I have code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
     
struct Foo {
    Foo(std::string t):text(t){}
    //destructor deleted
        
    std::string text;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> v;
        
    v.push_back(Foo("foo 1"));
    v.push_back(Foo("foo 2"));
    v.push_back(Foo("foo 3"));
      
    for(auto& foo : v){
        std::cout<<foo.text<<"\n";
    }
      
    Foo fooBack = std::move(v.back());
      
    std::cout<<fooBack.text<<"\n";
      
    for(auto& foo : v){
        std::cout<<foo.text<<"\n";
    }
}
```

`std::move()` in this case doesn't steal the return variable. Is there a way to avoid the excess copy?

This is the result:

```
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
foo 3
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
```

new code based on sugestions(dont know if keep asking on same thread dont know if that was what i expected , the reaon i was doind all this move is to reduce code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
 
struct Foo {
        Foo(std::string t):text(t){
            std::cout<<text<<" construct foo called \n";
        }
        Foo(const Foo& f){
            text = f.text;
            std::cout<<text<<"copy construct foo called \n";
        }
        Foo(Foo&& f){
            text = std::move(f.text);
            std::cout<<text<<"move construct foo called \n";
        
        }
        /*
    ~Foo() {
    }
    */
    
    std::string text;
};
int main()
{
    
    std::vector<Foo> v;
    
  v.emplace_back("foo 1");
  v.emplace_back("foo 2");
  v.emplace_back("foo 3");
  
  for(auto&& foo : v){
    std::cout<<foo.text<<"\n";
  }
  
  Foo fooBack = std::move(v.back());
  v.pop_back();
  
  std::cout<<fooBack.text<<"\n";
  
  for(auto&& foo : v){
    std::cout<<foo.text<<"\n";
  }
  
}
```

new results to see it in action

```
foo 1 construct foo called 
foo 2 construct foo called 
foo 1copy construct foo called 
foo 3 construct foo called 
foo 1copy construct foo called 
foo 2copy construct foo called 
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
foo 3move construct foo called 
foo 3
foo 1
foo 2
```

Comment: Get rid of the empty destructor.  Writing empty destructors can cause the compiler to generate less-efficient code, [as seen here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65e1d45005c87c8a)

Comment: You dont need to move a temporary. If you want to avoid a copy, try providing your class a move constructor.

Comment: It occurred to me to mention this, I think you might misunderstand `std::move` it doesn't move anything. All it does is perform a cast.

Comment: i thoght it did some moving, most tutorials i read did explained with steal, now i am confuced is what i need move for.

Comment: http://cppatomic.blogspot.com/2018/02/modern-effective-c-understanding.html?m=1 should clarify? I'd give scott meyer a read.

Comment: @user3709120 `std::move()` itself is just a type-cast to an rvalue reference, it doesn't steal anything on its own.  It is actually the job of move constructors and move assignment operators that take rvalue references as input to do the actual stealing.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the moved-from `Foo` object's `text` remains unchanged after being moved from due to short string optimization.  The state of a `std::string` is undefined after being moved from; it is not guaranteed to be empty.

Comment: According to https://godbolt.org/z/NWqqkT the result for the posted code is wrong

Answer (score 3):

The statement `Foo fooBack = std::move(v.back());` does not *remove* the last `Foo` object from the vector at all, but it does *move the content* of that object to your `fooBack` variable, due to a compiler-generated move constructor for `Foo`.  However, the original `Foo` object itself is still in the vector, which is why your 2nd `for` loop still sees that object.  The object just may not have a `text` value anymore to print, because `fooBack` stole it.

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/dzZczs)

That being said, it is *possible* that in your case, `std::string` is utilizing "Short String Optimization" (where small string values are kept in a fixed buffer inside the `std::string` class itself to avoid allocating memory dynamically when not needed) in such a way that a "move" from one `std::string` to another simply makes a *copy* of that fixed buffer's data, leaving the original `std::string` unchanged.  Which would explain why your 2nd `for` loop is still showing `"foo 3"` in the vector after "moving" `v.back()` to the `fooBack` variable - it was really a copy, not a move.

If you want to actually remove the last `Foo` object from the vector, you can use [`v.pop_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) for that, eg:

```
Foo fooBack = std::move(v.back());
v.pop_back(); // <-- add this
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/zxCwEy)

On a side note, your `push_back()`'s should be using `emplace_back()` instead, to avoid creating temporary `Foo` objects that have to be moved from during the pushes:

```
//v.push_back(Foo("foo 1"));
//v.push_back(Foo("foo 2"));
//v.push_back(Foo("foo 3"));
v.emplace_back("foo 1");
v.emplace_back("foo 2");
v.emplace_back("foo 3");
```

Comment: I think part of OP's confusion comes from the fact that the moved-from object's `text` _isn't_ empty after being moved from in their example output (likely due to short string optimization).  It may be worthwhile to mention that a `std::string` is not guaranteed to be empty after being moved from.

Comment: @MilesBudnek "*the moved-from object's text isn't empty after being moved from*" - it should be. [It does in my test](https://ideone.com/dzZczs). "*It may be worthwhile to mention that a std::string is not guaranteed to be empty after being moved from*" - yes, it is. Whether SSO is used or not, `operator<<` will still do the right thing.

Comment: It's not.  From [string.cons](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.cons#3): _Remarks: In the second form, `str` is left in a valid but unspecified state._  It's entirely legal for the moved-from string to still contain data.

Comment: @MilesBudnek That may be what the standard says, but in practice it doesn't make sense for an implementation of a `std::string` move constructor/assignment to leave data behind in the source `std::string`. It wouldn't be much of a move if it did. But whatever, I have added it to my answer.

Comment: The whole point of the standard is to define behavior that you can rely on. While its true that it doesn't make any sense to leave data behind in the string, its not up to the standard to impose the restriction that it _must_ zero out that data. The platform you're compiling on might just cause that to be a very costly operation. Hence the wording. Its best not to rely on it being empty. You shouldn't use an object after you move from it anyways, except maybe to assign it new data or "reset" it in some way. i.e. you shouldn't care if it is or isn't empty.

Comment: @Taekahn "*You shouldn't use an object after you move from it anyways, except maybe to assign it new data or "reset" it in some way*" - true enough.